# Android MVVM, can you observe LiveData inside an ViewModel with another LiveData object?

Tags: android, subject

In my application I use this ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel(){
    val hasMessages = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val messages = MutableLiveData<List<Message>>()

}
```

I have code hooked up so that if indeed the user has messages the list will be populated and the boolean will be updated, which seems redundant

they are two different variables because when hasMessages is set to true the user can see a button on their toolbar and when they press it they go to the fragment that shows the messages so they can see them

is there a way to set up hasMessages so that it becomes LiveData that derives from the messages list?

something like RxJava's AsyncSubject would work in this case but I can't figure out how to make that work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Transformations.map()

```
      val messages = MutableLiveData<List<Message>>()

      val hasMessages: LiveData<Boolean> = Transformations.map(messages) {
         it.isNotEmpty()
      }
```